# Unable to make proxy request with https module

Tags: node.js, https, proxy

I'm behind a proxy. I am trying to download a `zip` file from `storage.googleapis.com` with a node script.

I have `HTTPS_PROXY` and `HTTP_PROXY` set as environment variables for the process I am in and `curl` works with this command and the file downloads properly.

```
curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Mac/515411/chrome-mac.zip
```

This is the node script. The status code returns a `407` when I run this in node. Why? The Proxy Agent is set, and it's working perfectly fine with `curl`.

```
const URL = require('url')
const ProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
const getProxyForUrl = require('proxy-from-env').getProxyForUrl;
const https = require('https')

const url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Mac/515411/chrome-mac.zip'

function requestOptions(url, method = 'GET') {
    /** @type {Object} */
    const result = URL.parse(url);
    result.method = method;

    const proxyURL = getProxyForUrl(url);
    if (proxyURL) {
      /** @type {Object} */
      const parsedProxyURL = URL.parse(proxyURL);
      parsedProxyURL.secureProxy = parsedProxyURL.protocol === 'https:';

      result.agent = new ProxyAgent(parsedProxyURL);
    }
    console.log(result)
    return result;
  }

https.get(requestOptions(url), response => {
    console.log(response.statusCode)
})
```

Comment: `407` is `Proxy Authentication Required`, but when I pass `username` and `password` into the proxy globals I get `unable to get local issuer certificate`, not to mention should work because `secureProxy` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

adding `result.rejectUnauthorized = false` fixes it

```
function requestOptions(url, method = 'GET') {
    /** @type {Object} */
    const result = URL.parse(url);
    result.method = method;

    const proxyURL = getProxyForUrl(url);
    if (proxyURL) {
      /** @type {Object} */
      const parsedProxyURL = URL.parse(proxyURL);
      parsedProxyURL.secureProxy = parsedProxyURL.protocol === 'https:';

      result.agent = new ProxyAgent(parsedProxyURL);
    }
    result.rejectUnauthorized = false
    return result;
}
```